# How do I create a template subclass file in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm creating a static library for other developers. Some of the classes are meant to be overridden, similar to UIKit classes like UITableViewController.

How do I create templates that will automatically be filled in after the developer creates a new subclass of my class? For example, when they create XXController using xcode's file->new method, I want the subclassed file to contain some boiler plate code that I specify.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making use of Xcode 4 its difficult to create templates. See instructions here http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/11/a-minimal-project-template-for-xcode-4/ Also checkout https://github.com/MrGando/Xcode-4-Template-Generator which is a python script which helps to build a very basic TemplateInfo.plist.

Have you considered using IntelliJ's AppCode which has bare-bones but much easier template creation feature.